# How to show a progress loading indicator with Kendo.Grid() inside a modal pop up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I defined a `Grid` inside of my `Partial View` that is loaded into a modal popup.

This is the part of the `Grid`:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ReportReversalsData)
     .Name("MyGrid")
     .
     .
     .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Events(e => e.Error("ShowError"))
                .Read(r => r.Action("MyMethod", "MyController", Model))
     )
)
```

Now, I want to shoe a progress loading indicator inside of the Grid every time the data is loading.

I tried to define a javascript method `showLoading` that is invoked on `RequestStart` event of the grid:

```
.Events(e => e.Error("CheckError").RequestStart('showLoading'))
```

And this is `showLoading` function and some `.css` styling required for the `kendo.ui.progress`:

```
<style>
    .k-grid-content > .k-loading-mask
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .k-grid > .k-loading-mask
    {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .k-grid > .k-loading-mask > .k-loading-color
    {
        opacity: .7;
    }

</style>

<script>
    function showLoading()
    {
       kendo.ui.progress("#MyGrid", true)
    }
</script>
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

What am I missing, or my approach is completely wrong and there is some other way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to use the plain text id, use the actual kendo element:

```
function showLoading()
{
    var myGrid = $("#myGrid").getKendoGrid();
    kendo.ui.progress(myGrid, true);
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestions, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you certain that the error is occurring at this stage of the app?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help. I found the reason why it did not work. `k-loading-image` class`s `background-image` property was set in a different `.css` file with the same name that was rendered by `@Styles.render`. After all I did not even need to have all the methods I used trying to solve the issue

Comment: thanks a lot my friend